# How to upload multiple Maven artifacts (.m2/repository folder) to Nexus 3 offline?

Tags: java, maven, upload, nexus, offline

**What am I trying to do?**

- Computer 1: Internet access, I have an IntelliJ Maven project with Maven artifacts downloaded into my `.m2/repository`.
- Computer 2: No internet access, has Nexus 3 (repository manager) which I need to upload the Maven artifacts into.

I transfer the Maven artifacts from Computer 1 and Computer 2 via CD no problem. I can upload these files to Nexus 3, albeit 1 at a time. I'm trying to see if there's a way to upload multiple Maven artifacts to Nexus 3.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

Currently I can access Nexus 3 and upload 1 package at a time. (uploaded via `http:localhost:8181/#browse/upload:maven-releases`, `.jar` and `.pom` files respectively)

**What do I expect the result to be?**

This works fine, but also looking for an efficient method.

**What is the actual result?**

I'm able to update the version numbers through an iterative process where IntelliJ, after each attempted build, tells me which artifacts I'm missing, and I upload those (.jar and .pom) one at a time.

**What I think the problem could be?**

Unsure. I would think there's a mass upload button or if I can drop the `.m2/repository` somewhere in Nexus 3, but not sure how to.

Comment: Does the nexus has internet access?

Comment: Nexus does not have internet access since it's on Computer 2.

Comment: I would connect the nexus with internet. build on the first computer (dependencies will be automatically being downloading onto Computer 1 and also into nexus (if correctly configured) and now you can use them on computer 2 and consume all dependencies via Nexus...without internet access.. That's the usual way to go...

Comment: Did you find a workaround for your issue?

Comment: @htkhtk Wasn't able to unfortunately and not on that project anymore so no reason to, sorry for the bad news, thanks for your patience.